# Is it possible to apply multiple ColorFilters on a Drawable?

Tags: java, android

Is it possible to apply multiple ColorFilters on a Drawable by i.e. apply the first ColorFilter on the drawable and then apply a second one on the mutated drawable?

Sample Code:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View returnView = super.getDropDownView(position, convertView, parent);
    Drawable d = returnView.getBackground();
    d.setColorFilter(0xFFF1F633, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
    // overrides the first color filter
    d.setColorFilter(0xFFEEEEEE, PorterDuff.Mode.LIGHTEN);
    returnView.setBackgroundDrawable(d);
    return returnView;
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16346545/apply-many-color-filters-to-the-same-drawable