# Apply many color filters to the same drawable

Tags: android, chaining, android-drawable, colorfilter

I want to apply several color filters in chain to a drawable. Is that possible? Or maybe to create a filter that is the combination of the filters I want to apply.

For example, I would like:

```
Drawable d = ...;
d.setColorFilter(0x3F000000, Mode.OVERLAY).setColorFilter(0xFF2D2D2D, Mode.SCREEN)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is the approach I ended using: Manipulate the `Drawable` bitmap on a `Canvas` and apply as many layers as I need, using `Paint`, it works not only for color filters, but also for any kind of image blending.

```
...
Drawable myBackground = createBackground(getResources().getColor(R.color.Green)); 
setBackgroundDrawable(myBackground);
...

private Drawable createBackground(int color) {

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
    Bitmap buttonImage = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.btn_image);
    Bitmap buttonShadows = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.btn_shadows);
    Bitmap buttonHighLights = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.btn_highlights);
    Bitmap result = Bitmap.createBitmap(buttonImage.getWidth(), buttonImage.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

    canvas.setBitmap(result);
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setFilterBitmap(false);

    // Color
    paint.setColorFilter(new PorterDuffColorFilter(color, Mode.MULTIPLY));
    canvas.drawBitmap(buttonImage, 0, 0, paint);
    paint.setColorFilter(null);
    // Shadows
    paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.MULTIPLY));
    canvas.drawBitmap(buttonShadows, 0, 0, paint);
    // HighLights
    paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SCREEN));
    canvas.drawBitmap(buttonHighLights, 0, 0, paint);

    paint.setXfermode(null);
    return new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), result);
}
```

**Caveat:** `setBackgroundDrawable(Drawable d)` is deprecated, while `setBackground(Drawable d)` is only available from api 16 on, so if you have like me a min target api-14 max target api-17 you have no "clean" way to set the drawable as background. I sticked with the deprecated call.

Answer (score 1):

After searching a lot I didn't find an answer that quite satisfy my needs.
However i've stumbled upon [this video](https://youtu.be/LNNyVVLk-ms) called "Practical Image Processing in Android" from 2018 which pointed me to the right direction : the `ImageFilterView` class. You can find the [documentation here](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/constraintlayout/utils/widget/ImageFilterView?hl=fr).

Seeing the way they apply multiple filters on the same image is very instructive and happen not to be so hard.
It consist of using a `ColorMatrix` and concatening multiple other `ColorMatrix` by calling the `ColorMatrix.postConcat` method. By the end, the result contains all the filters you've applied to it.

Here's a sample code to change the brightness and saturation of an image.

```
package com.rewieer.imagefilters;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.graphics.ColorMatrix;
import android.graphics.ColorMatrixColorFilter;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.SeekBar;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
  private ImageView image;
  private SeekBar brightnessSeekBar;
  private SeekBar saturationSeekBar;
  private BitmapDrawable defaultDrawable;

  private int brightness = 0;
  private int saturation = 0;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    image = findViewById(R.id.mainImage);
    defaultDrawable = (BitmapDrawable) image.getDrawable();

    brightnessSeekBar = findViewById(R.id.brightnessSeekBar);
    saturationSeekBar = findViewById(R.id.saturationSeekBar);

    brightnessSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
      @Override
      public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
        brightness = progress;
        redraw();
      }

      @Override
      public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

      }

      @Override
      public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

      }
    });

    saturationSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
      @Override
      public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
        saturation = progress;
        redraw();
      }

      @Override
      public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

      }

      @Override
      public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

      }
    });
  }

  public void redraw() {
    ColorMatrix matrix = new ColorMatrix();
    matrix.postConcat(new ColorMatrix(new float[]{
        1f, 0, 0, 0, brightness,
        0, 1f, 0, 0, brightness,
        0, 0, 1f, 0, brightness,
        0, 0, 0, 1f, 0
    }));

    float MS = 1.0F - saturation;
    float Rt = 0.2999F * MS;
    float Gt = 0.587F * MS;
    float Bt = 0.114F * MS;

    matrix.postConcat(new ColorMatrix(new float[]{
        Rt + saturation, Gt, Bt, 0, 0,
        Rt, Gt + saturation, Bt, 0, 0,
        Rt, Gt, Bt + saturation, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 1f, 0
    }));

    image.setColorFilter(new ColorMatrixColorFilter(matrix));
  }
}
```

The most important method here being `redraw`.
By looking at the `ImageFilterView` source code we can also apply warmth and constrat to the image, very easily, by simple copy-pasting their algorithm.

Comment: Unfortunately, `ImageFilterView` is not supported by View Binding.